# Write form data to SQL database

Tags: php, sql

I keep getting unexpected ";". I cannot figure out what the problem is. If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.

send_post.php

```
<?php
//Create connect
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","tasks","tasks15!","tasks");
//Sending form data to sql db.
mysqli_query ($connect,"INSERT INTO tasks (CompanyName, ContactName,  Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, Phone1, Phone2, Fax1)
VALUES ('$_POST[tasks_CompanyName]', '$_POST[tasks_ContactName]',     '$_POST[tasks_Address1]', '$_POST[tasks_Address2]' ,'$_POST[tasks_City]','$_POST[tasks_State],'$_POST[tasks_Zip]', '$_POST[tasks_Phone1]','$_POST[tasks_Phone2]','$_POST[tasks_Fax1]');"

?>
```

index.html

```
<form action="send_post.php" method="post">
<h1>Customer Information</h1>

<h3>Company Name</h3> <input type="text" name="tasks_CompanyName"> <br>
<h2>Customer Name</h2><h3>First Name</h3> <input type="text" name="tasks_fname"><br>
<h3> Last Name</h3><input type="text" name="tasks_lname"><br>
<h3> Address 1 </h3>  <input type="text" name="tasks_Address1"><br>

<h3> Address 2</h3>   <input type="text" name="tasks_Address2"><br>

<h3>City</h3><input type="text" name="tasks_City"><br>

<h3>State</h3> <input type="text" name="tasks_State"><br>

<h3>Zip</h3>    <input type="text" name="tasks_Zip"><br>

<h3>Phone 1</h3><input type="text" name="tasks_Phone1"><br>

<h3>Phone 2</h3> <input type="text" name="tasks_Phone2"><br>

<h3>Fax 1</h3>     <input type="text" name="tasks_Fax1"><br>


<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: '$_POST[tasks_Fax1]');" to '$_POST[tasks_Fax1]');");

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_query ($connect,"INSERT INTO tasks (CompanyName, ContactName,  Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, Phone1, Phone2, Fax1)
VALUES ('$_POST[tasks_CompanyName]', '$_POST[tasks_ContactName]',     '$_POST[tasks_Address1]', '$_POST[tasks_Address2]' ,'$_POST[tasks_City]','$_POST[tasks_State],'$_POST[tasks_Zip]', '$_POST[tasks_Phone1]','$_POST[tasks_Phone2]','$_POST[tasks_Fax1]');"
```

There are a few errors in this line. 
`$_POST` is an array, and as such you must access the value using the name of the key - such as `$_POST["tasks_Address1"]` rather than `$_POST[tasks_Address1]`.

You've also got the semicolon on the inside of the quotes at the end of the line: `'$_POST[tasks_Fax1]');"`. You'll want to put this semicolon on the outside: `'$_POST[tasks_Fax1]')";`.

Your SQL is also potentially subject to SQL injection. Have a read of some resources such as [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some ideas on how to make your code safe from malicious input.

Comment: i think the semicolon at the end can stay (since it ends the sql statement), but addidional semicolon should be put at the end of the line to end php statement

Comment: @flynorc you're right; you can have one at the end of the SQL statement but it's not required

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding ");" missing at the end of your mysqli_query line.

send_post.php:5

```
<?php
mysqli_query ($connect,"INSERT INTO tasks
  (CompanyName, ContactName, Address1, 
   Address2, City, State, Zip, Phone1,
   Phone2, Fax1)
VALUES
  ('$_POST[tasks_CompanyName]', '$_POST[tasks_ContactName]',
   '$_POST[tasks_Address1]',    '$_POST[tasks_Address2]',
   '$_POST[tasks_City]',        '$_POST[tasks_State],
   '$_POST[tasks_Zip]',     '$_POST[tasks_Phone1]',   
   '$_POST[tasks_Phone2]',  '$_POST[tasks_Fax1]'
  );");
?>
```

Note that it's dangerous to record POST data w/o verification as it may lead to XSS and SQL injection hacks.